# How to output a simple textfile on a webpage using python and HTML?

Tags: python, html, cron

I am streaming a camera to a webpage using Raspi Camera and a simple webpage using Python/HTML - https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html#web-streaming

I am wanting to add a simple metric like temperature but dont want to (and cant) make system calls.. 
Thinking about making a cronjob to update a textfile with a value (i.e., temp) and then getting the webpage to read and output the textfile to the webpage... what is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: why don't use cron to generate directly HTML with these values.

Comment: if you already have HTML then use `open()`, `read()` in `do_GET` to get data from file - and use these data to generate result.

Comment: @furas how do I do that?

Comment: `f = open('data.txt')` `text = f.read()` , and string formatting  `"<html>{}</html>".format(text)` to put text from `text` in place of `{}` in string. See: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: @furas im wondering if you can help me I feel im close.. I am trying:
 
`filex = open("/home/user/folder/test.txt", "rb")
testx = filex.read()
self.wfile.write(testx)`

it could be because this section of `"elif self.path == '/index.html'"` is already serving `"self.wfile.write(content)"` ??
where "content" is `"content = PAGE.encode('utf-8')"` and  PAGE is just a whole lot of HTML written at the top of the file... based off the simple webpage linked at the top

Comment: what is the problem ? BTW: if you want to send only `textx` then you have to send first `self.send_header('Content-Length', len(textx))`. If you want to send both `content` and `textx` then you will need `len(textx) + len(content)` but you should rather use string formating like in previous comment `"<html> ... rest ... {}</html>".format(textx)` to put `textx` inside `content`.

Comment: OR maybe you should use popular web frameworks like [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) or `Django` instead of module `http`. `Flask` (and other web framemorks) can use [templates](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates)